# why awakeFromNib can't be called in controllers?

Tags: ios

I am a new developer, two questions as follows

1. In controller, why can't I call the `awakeFromNib` method?

   ```c
   -(void)awakeFromeNib
   {
       NSLog(@"awakeFromNib");// can't be printed ?
   }
   ```
2. Do the methods `awakeFromNib` and `initWithNibName` , `layoutSubviews` have some relations?
   When and where should I use them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `- (void)awakeFromNib` is only called inside of an object that is being directly loaded from a nib or storyboard. This is usually **not** a UIViewController.
2. So, the reason `awakeFromNib` is not on a view controller is that the view controller is the one that is calling its subviews to awake from the nib as set from the method `initWithNibName:bundle:`.  The `layoutSubviews` method is also called in a subclass of UIView since a view may have subviews that it needs to layout. If I'm not mistaken, the `layoutSubviews` on a UIView gets called after `awakeFromNib`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: `awakeFromNib` is sent to all objects instantiated from a nib file, not only `UIView` and subclasses.

Comment: I've edited the post. You're right about the instantiation of other objects from a nib file.

Answer (score 1):

`awakeFromNib` is called on the controller after all the connections in it's nib are created and set up.

`initWithNibName` is the designated initialiser for the class. You call this when you are creating the controller in code.

`layoutSubviews` is a method that you implement that allows you to give precise layout to subviews.

You should also know about `initWithCoder` which is the initialiser that is called when the controller is created from a xib file or a storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Your view controller was likely not awaken from a NIB and instead initialized  `initWithNibName:bundle:`.  Only objects that are initialized from a NIB get `awakeFromNib`.

There is a method that gets called when the view is initialized, either from a NIB or `loadView`: `viewDidLoad`

Using `viewDidLoad` accomplishes pretty much the same thing you'd be expecting from `awakeFromNib`.

You may be able to use `awakeFromNib` when your view controller is created from a storyboard, as Abizem suggests, but that will still invoke `viewDidLoad` immediately afterward.